# Calculation in same page using PHP

Tags: javascript, validation

I have to enter only "**0**" or "**1**" or "**0.5**" in the textbox as input, using PHP. Already I used the code for, enter only numbers in the textbox:

```
<input type="text" id="tla1" name="tlaCasual"  maxlength="3" onkeyup="enterNumber()" onblur="calculate_casualleave()"  style="width:40px;" >
```

and the javascript is:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function enterNumber()
{    
    var e = document.getElementById('tla1');
    if (!/^[0-9]+$/.test(e.value)) 
    {
        alert("Please enter only number.");
        e.value = e.value.substring(0,e.value.length-1);
    }
}   
</script>
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: Please state your problem

Comment: I don't see PHP..to validate with PHP you have to send the form to a PHP script

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  if the user wants to give the input in textbox, he could give only '0' or '1' or '0.5' (three inputs only). I hope, now you understand my question.

Comment: you want to validate, that the input is either `0` or `1` or `0.5`?

Comment: ...and you want to test if he typed it correctly and would like to ask why this code doesn't work, don't you?

Comment: why not work with a select box?

Comment: If you really want to enforce 3 values only, use a radio group, not input text with js, makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with PHP, PHP is a server sided language. You also do not point out what exactly you want to calculate, but 
I guess you're asking for the correct Regex to allow only "0", "0.0", "0.5", "1" and "1.0", which is `^(0(\.0|\.5)?|1(\.0)?)$`

for only "0", "0.5" and "1" use `^(0(\.5)?|1)$`

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why use regular expression to test THREE possible values.

```
if((e.value!=1) && (e.value!=0.5) && (e.value!=0)){
 // error
 }
else{
 // ok
}
```

Comment: Hey Voitcus, thanks for your immediate help. Its working fine. I get the exact result what i think.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that your problem is "It does not work".

This is true that the regex is not accepting "0.5", so I guess you just update it to :

```
   function enterNumber(){

   var e = document.getElementById('tla1');

      if (!/^[0-9\.]+$/.test(e.value)) 
    { 
    alert("Please enter only number.");
    e.value = e.value.substring(0,e.value.length-1);
    }
    }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: this would allow 0.3 as well

Comment: yes, indeed. I thought it was only sample values, not a discrete list of allowed values. Otherwise, why bother with an input text for 3 values ?

Comment: This seems to be a little bit of overhead for only 3 values, yes. But if this is somehow the first draft and it get's expanded later to value with a specific pattern, it might be valid to do it with regex.